# Resize all Bootstrap inputs and controls globally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any easy way to resize all Bootstrap 3 control elements like inputs, select, textarea etc?
I am trying to go though the variables in the scss files but one thing leads to another and I get lost. Thank you in advanced if somebody has an idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fiddling with the `@input-height-base` variable which is by default defined as `(@line-height-computed + (@padding-base-vertical * 2) + 2)`

Comment: So I just remove these line and replace it with a numer value?

Comment: Oh! The buttons are now with the original sizes :(

Answer (score 1):

You can completely customize pretty much all values on the official site for Bootstrap, via the Customize section.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Enter whatever values you need here, and you can even remove elements/features you don't plan to use to make your Bootstrap implementation for your site a lot smaller. Click the download link at the bottom when you're done, and the download also includes a .json file with all the items you selected, so if you need to make adjustments after the fact you can simply upload the .json file to enter all your previous selections, then make your changes and download a new copy.